# What do I need in order to make Ubuntu 14.04 LTS see my newly-purchased Blu Ray writer?

Tags: blu-ray

I just bought a Blu Ray writer ([Pioneer BDR-TD05AS 6x Blu-Ray BD-RE Writer Burner](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KWHJWXM)).

[image]

The writer itself is internal, but I bought a special box (3Q ODD)

[image]

that you put it in and then connect the whole thing to the laptop with a USB cord. Now, when I plug the cord into my laptop, nothing happens. I guess I need some sort of driver to make the laptop see the writer and software to burn Blu Ray disks. I've never done this before. Could you please help me figure out all the things I need in order to be able to burn Blu Ray disks?

```
misha@hp-laptop:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0bda:5775 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. HP "Truevision HD" laptop camera
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0458:003a KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) NetScroll+ Mini Traveler / Genius NetScroll 120
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Could you please update your question with the output of `lsusb`?